# How can I define a symbolic function in python?

Tags: python, sympy

I am writing a very simple macro for my thesis.

I want to define a symbolic function with 4 input parameters: two of them correspond to numerical values but the other two are symbolic variables that will be used for integrating the function.

Here is the code of the function:

```
def VelocityDistribution_notNorm(v_DM,costheta,v_0,v_e):
    return exp(-(v_DM**2 + v_e**2 + 2*v_DM*v_e*costheta)/(v_0**2));
```

v_0 and v_e correspond to numerical values and V_DM and costheta are the two symbolic variables. 
In a different function I called the previous function in the following way:

```
v_0 = 220 #km/s
v_e = 232 #km/s
v_DM = Symbol("v_DM")
cosTheta = Symbol("cosTheta")
integrand_0 = v_DM * VelocityDistribution_notNorm(v_DM,v_e,v_0,cosTheta)
```

Also I imported the following modules:

```
from math import *
from sympy import *
from sympy.functions.elementary.exponential import *
from scipy import *
from scipy.constants import *
```

but I get this error when I try to run the macro:

```
  File "prova.py", line 38, in VelocityDistribution_notNorm
    return exp(-(v_DM**2 + v_e**2 + 2*v_DM*v_e*costheta)/(v_0**2));
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `sympy`? If so, adding the specific tag to the question might help

Answer (score 0):

the function `exp` is in the `math` package. Import it before use:

```
from math import exp
```

Comment: I believe he's using the `sympy` version (he's missing the imports in his code, but the use of `Symbol` points that way). If that's the case, `exp` would also presumably be `sympy.exp`.

Comment: Indeed, was a bit quick, there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing symbolic and explicit functions, here. You can solve this by not importing anything from math. This is why it is generally advised against doing `from xyz import *`

```
from sympy import *
import scipy

def VelocityDistribution_notNorm(v_DM,costheta,v_0,v_e):
    return exp(-(v_DM**2 + v_e**2 + 2*v_DM*v_e*costheta)/(v_0**2));

v_0 = 220 #km/s
v_e = 232 #km/s
v_DM = Symbol("v_DM")
cosTheta = Symbol("cosTheta")
integrand_0 = VelocityDistribution_notNorm(v_DM,v_e,v_0,cosTheta)
```